# Parse out reserved characters in Oracle Text search/query?

Tags: c#, oracle-text

I am designing a web app and there is a search page in it with the ability to do full text search (I have created a CONTEXT index on my text columns of interest).  With [Oracle you can do a CONTAINS query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/cqspcl.htm) that runs the full text search and returns you the results - this is great, except if you put in a reserved character e.g.:

> "ice* AND places AND Alaska"

the fact you put an '*' after 'ice', will get you an Oracle error i.e.,

```
ORA-29902: error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
```

What is the most graceful way to avoid this - I know you could filter out reserved characters and keywords - but I would have thought there would be a more elegant way. If you know of such a thing, I would be really interest to know :-)

---

NOTE: Here is the code that runs the Oracle text search, nothing spectacular:

```
 OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT ref_id, title, table_name, description FROM v_all_media WHERE CONTAINS (title, :pTitle) > 0", conn);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("pTitle", title);
 OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

> {}
>
> Use braces to escape a string of characters or symbols. Everything
>   within a set of braces in considered part of the escape sequence.
>
> When you use braces to escape a single character, the escaped
>   character becomes a separate token in the query.
>
> \
>
> Use the backslash character to escape a single character or symbol.
>   Only the character immediately following the backslash is escaped.

See [Special Characters in Queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/text.920/a96518/cqspcl.htm#20741)